# svn patch error: patch: **** misordered hunks! output would be garbled

Tags: svn, unix

I am working on a unix machine & I did a diff on my old sandbox:

`svn diff -x -w . > ~todays.diff`

and applied the patch on a new sandbox:

`patch -p0 -i ~todays.diff`

but I am getting these errors:

`Hmm...  The next patch looks like a unified diff to me...`

`The text leading up to this was:`

`patch: **** misordered hunks! output would be garbled`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try "svn patch" (svn help patch), maybe it works

Comment: Are "patch" and "svn patch" two different things??

Comment: Yes they are. Btw, I've also often used just patch for patching svn diffs, but with a little bit different syntax: "patch -p0 < patchfile", but the proper way is using svn patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use OS `patch` for applying patch from `svn diff`, you have `svn patch` (with resolving merge-conflicts in process, if they will appear)
2. If both WCs are binded to the same repo, why you don't want to use "commit"-"update" procedure?

Comment: 1. I had this doubt, I thought patch & svn patch are the same thing, I didn't see on any website, anyone using svn patch.
2. These are different releases. I did changes on one release but turns out the release wan't stable. So, now ptaching the stable release with my changes to test it.

Comment: @tarun27sh - even for different releases (trees in repository) you can use merge in SVN: commit SANDBOX1 to SOME/URL/IN/REPO, merge WC of SANDBOX2 with SOME/URL/IN/REPO